# upvoted after a down vote, but points are not reversed?

Tags: bug

I noticed from https://music.stackexchange.com/users/18447/mey?tab=reputation that my points are not reversed when a previously down voted answer gets upvoted. As far as i know, i would have got a +5 to replace the -2. Would greatly appreciate an action on this. Thanks☺

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, that's a borderline bug. The problem is that your answer has become `community-wiki` inbetween, and when a post becomes `cw`, you don't lose the rep you gained so far, but you don't get any more reputation (the post is "community owned" now). Unfortunately, in your case it means that the `-2` rep you lost wasn't gained back. Obviously, it wasn't a revised downvote, but rather an independent upvote (someone with enough rep to see this could verify it).

IMHO it would make sense to still count upvotes as counter-acting previous downvotes and vice versa, even after the post has been `cw`ed, I mean, if the score gets closer to zero, the rep gain should be changed to reflect this.

Anyways, just remember this and you'll be fine: *Rep is a non-significant number.*

Comment: Thanks NReilingh and yo' for explanation and clarification.

Answer (score 3):

- Reputation gained from votes is not absolute, it is cumulative.
- Reputation changes only occur on questions and answers that are NOT community wiki.
- Upvotes on questions gain 5 reputation, upvotes on answers gain 10 reputation.

This means, if an answer had one downvote and two upvotes, the total reputation change will be **+18**. (`-2 * 1 downvote + 10 * 2 upvotes`)

> Downvotes don't go away -- they will even become visible to you once you reach the [Established User](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilege.

However, in the case of the vote events referenced in your question, the upvote occurred on your post after you made it [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), so the upvote did not confer a reputation change. Making a post community wiki does not revert reputation changes conferred by downvotes that occurred prior.

Please try to consult the [Help Center](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/help) and Google for questions about core site functionality before coming to meta. We are happy to help, but this topic is exhaustively discussed in posts such as the following: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history